# cannot read the next data row for the dataset

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a query that is working in sql management studio, but when I run this is SSRS/Visual Studio I get the error "cannot read the next data row for the dataset dataset1. Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"

```
select

    concat(
    right(replace(oe_hdr.po_no, '-', ''),8),
    right(concat('000',job_price_line.line_no),3),
    format(oe_pick_ticket_detail.unit_quantity, '00000000'),
    cast(job_price_line.customer_part_no as char(20)),
    oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no)  as [po/line/release/qty/cust part no as 20 characters / invoice]




    from oe_pick_ticket

join oe_pick_ticket_detail on oe_pick_ticket_detail.pick_ticket_no = oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no 
join oe_hdr on oe_hdr.order_no = oe_pick_ticket.order_no
join job_price_hdr on oe_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid = job_price_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid
join job_price_line on job_price_line.inv_mast_uid = oe_pick_ticket_detail.inv_mast_uid and job_price_line.job_price_hdr_uid = oe_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid 
join ship_to on ship_to.ship_to_id = oe_hdr.address_id
join branch on branch.branch_id = ship_to.default_branch
join customer on customer.customer_id = oe_hdr.customer_id

where oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no in ('1218972', '1218983')
and job_price_line.row_status_flag != '705'
and oe_pick_ticket_detail.ship_quantity > '0'
```

[image]

But when I run this for SSRS - and I add more parameters to my where clause like this:

```
    where oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no in (@invoiceno1, @invoiceno2, @invoiceno3,
     @invoiceno4, @invoiceno5, @invoiceno6, @invoiceno7 ,@invoiceno8,
 @invoiceno9, @invoiceno10, @invoiceno11, @invoiceno12, @invoiceno13,
 @invoiceno14, @invoiceno15, @invoiceno16, @invoiceno17, @invoiceno18,
 @invoiceno19, @invoiceno20)
        and job_price_line.row_status_flag != '705'
        and oe_pick_ticket_detail.ship_quantity > '0'
```

It returns the error

[image]

Comment: Check the types of `invoice_no`, `row_status_flag` and `ship_quantity` in your tables, and make sure that you are using parameters of the SAME types, and that you fill those parameters correctly.

Comment: What is the datatype of `oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no`?

Comment: It seems your dataset is returning a nvarchar value but while processing the data it is trying to perform arithmetic operations against it which results in an error. try using `CDBL(Fields!YourField.Value)` in the expression you are using that column.

Comment: @peterb  Invoice_no is decimal(19,0) row_status_flag is int, Ship_quantity is decimal(19,9)

Comment: @WEI_DBA  Invoice_no is decimal(19,0)

Comment: So why are you comparing character data to decimal data? Remove the single quotes. What is the datatype of the parameters you are passing in?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to allow null expressions on all of my parameters. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I changed TIMING in Data source from 30 to 100. This solved my problem. My theory is that my Dataset was too big.

[image: Screenshot]